# Complete name instead of database record value

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, admin-generator

I have a database column that stores `ENUM` values, in this case I have `a` or `i` which means `active` or `inactive`.  How, in admin-generator module, can I display `Active` / `Inactive` instead of `a` / `i`? Any help?

**Edit: Display the Active or Inactive in index**
What I have now is as follow:

```
ID    Name   Active   Actions
1     Val1   a        Edit | Delete  
2     Val2   a        Edit | Delete
3     Val3   i        Edit | Delete
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
ID    Name   Active   Actions
1     Val1   Active   Edit | Delete  
2     Val2   Active   Edit | Delete
3     Val3   Inactive Edit | Delete
```

Or just write a `image_tag()` depending on values something like `checked.png` when value is `a` or `unchecked.png` when value is `i`.

Comment: Show a bit more of what you have and what you' ve tried so far

Comment: @ChristianGärtner I didn't do nothing yet because don't know how, I'm checking docs [here](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/06-Admin-Generator#chapter_06_sub_type) but still without know how to get this done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where and what you want to change is very vague, but here goes :

In index page, just use a partial to override the displayed value via generator.yml. [See symfony doc](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/fr/12?orm=Doctrine)

Otherwise, in form pages, create another form, edit the sfWidgetFormChoice to have the wanted label. Then update the form class used in the module also via generator.yml. [See symfony doc](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/06-Admin-Generator#chapter_06_sub_class)

Comment: I know how to achieve in forms by overriding the default widget but still don't know how to get this done at view levels meaning when I execute `index()` function. I read the docs but didn't find any help. Take a look at my edition, maybe this clarify a but what I'm looking for

Comment: As stated here [symfony doc](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/06-admin-generator#chapter_06_sub_fields), just render a partial. For this, create a partial **_active** in your template folder. Then, in your generator.yml, in _list_, in _display_, add the field _active

Comment: Ok, I understood now how to work with this part using partials but my question is: if column stores `a` or `i` where I should write the code to get `Active` for `a` and `Inactive` for `i` and how I show them in partial?

Comment: Totally up to you. It should be in a helper function as it is purely formatting to me, but I guess it would be much convenient to store this in your model class as you could reuse this easily.

Comment: could you please leave me some code for review? Just a example?